Updating the site on Julia
I am new to learning the Julia language.I read one book.I'm figuring it out a little bit .It's a hobby.It is difficult to find detailed language courses and little literature.The question is this:How do I update the site for example 5 times with an interval of 5 minutes?I was trying to figure out the HTTP library.jl But the code didn't work...It is interesting to understand the very principle of how the request update code works with a time delay.
using  HTTP, Gumbo,Cascadia

r = HTTP.get("https://time.is/")

r_parsed = parsehtml(String(r.body))

body = r_parsed.root[2]

City = body[2][2][1][3][1][1]
Time = body[2][2][2][1][1]

a = City[1].text
b = Time[1].text
println("City  $a \n Time  $b")

as I understand it, we need to carefully deal with the HTTP

First, in general, in Julia code runs faster and with fewer variable name related errors when the code that is run is placed within into one or more functions. Second, in order to repeatedly run code at a certain interval, you usually want to run in a loop, with pauses of the required length made with a function such as sleep(secs) which pauses execution for "secs" seconds. So for example:
using  HTTP, Gumbo, Cascadia

function getcitytime()
    r = HTTP.get("https://time.is/")      
    r_parsed = parsehtml(String(r.body))
    body = r_parsed.root[2]
    City = body[2][2][1][3][2][1]
    Time = body[2][2][2][1][1]
    return City[1].text, Time[1].text
end

function printcitytime(intervalminutes, nruns = 5)
    for _ in 1:nruns
        a, b = getcitytime()
        println("City  $a \n Time  $b")
        sleep(intervalminutes *  60)
    end
end

printcitytime(0.1)

Just a comment: parsing your XML or HTML structure with multiple indices as you are doing can work efficiently for a while, but is very fragile and hard to modify weeks or months later when the HTML of the web site changes even a little. It is good practice to carefully document why you index into the data as you do, to make it a bit easier to change correctly later when it breaks, as it will.

Thank you very much for the detailed answer to my question.I will analyze the information.
